# $P(x)=16x^2+25$ Factor the Polynomial completely.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

My first few attempts my professor said were right. My homework software, MindTap does not. Below are my previous entries that were all rejected and the other portion to the problem that I got right. Can you help find out where I went wrong or what MindTap might be looking for?

Wrong Entries:

$$(x+(5/4)i)(x-(5/4)i)$$

$$(4x-5)(4x+5)$$

$$16x^2+25$$

Thought it was worth a try since I couldn't factor it.

Correct Portion of My Answer:

Real Zeros = None

Complex Zeros = $(-5/4)i$ and $(5/4)i$ with multiplicity of $1$

Comment: Hint: what polynomial is $(x+(5/4)i)(x-(5/4)i)$ a factorisation of? What's the relation between that and your polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $25$ as $-(5i)^2$ and use difference of squares formula:
$x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$